# React onClick function within render() is undefined

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

With the react component below I am getting the error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'oncontactClick' of undefined
```

```
 class Contacts extends React.Component{
    constructor(props, contact){
      super(props);
      this.state ={ contacts: [] };
      this.oncontactClick = this.oncontactClick.bind(this);
    }
    oncontactClick(){
      console.log("contact clicked");
    }
    render(){
      var contacts = this.state.contacts;
      contacts = contacts.map(function(contact, index){
        return(
          <div key={index} className="contactcard" onClick={this.oncontactClick}>
            <div className="name">{contact.name}</div>
          </div>
        )
      });
      return(
        <div id="addcontainer">
          <form id="addinput">
            <input type="text" ref="name" placeholder="name" required/>
          </form>
          <ul>{contacts}</ul>
        </div>
      );
    }
  };
```

However, if I place the `onClick` in the `form "addinput"`, it works fine. Why is that the case and how can I get it to work within the `contactcard`? I would like to avoid using jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array.map takes two arguments :

First one is the iteratee.

Second one is what defines `this` in the iteratee.

This should works :

```
  contacts = contacts.map(function(contact, index){
    return(
      <div key={index} className="contactcard" onClick={this.oncontactClick}>
        <div className="name">{contact.name}</div>
      </div>
    )
  }, this);
```